# nsupdate instructions dyn.com are incomplete

Tags: dyndns, dynamic-dns, nsupdate

Using `nsupdate` for dynamic DNS TSIG Updates
To update a DNS server dynamically using TSIG for authorization, run `nsupdate` by doing the following:

```
$ nsupdate -d
> server update.dyndns.com
> zone $ZONE
> key $KEY_NAME $KEY_HMAC
> update add $HOST.$ZONE 60 A 10.0.0.1
> send
> quit
```

For dynamic DNS hosts, $ZONE should be the third level DNS name like `myhost.dyndns.org`

**But it doesn't explain what $HOST is expected to be?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect it to be the name of the host e.g. myhost as the zone would be dyndns.org.

Comment: Right. `nsupdate` requires the FQDN here. For instance `update add myserver.example.com 60 A 203.0.113.47`